# How to copy a file to a windows path with wildcards in it?

Tags: windows, cmd, copy

I am newbie to windows os. Please pardon my question if you feel it is like a noob question.

I am trying to copy a a file from one path to another path. The thing is that the destination path has a wildcard character in it. How to copy? I assumed it as a simple task, but not to be.

This is the command

```
copy *.zip "C:\MyCave\iso\SDG\cmpdir\copy test\ab\cd\*\gh"
```

The folder after `ab\cd` is dynamic. So I have tried to use wildcard, but this is throwing an error.

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

I want to copy files in directory `gh` in the path.

How to do it?

Regards

Comment: You can't have wildcard directories.

Comment: Can I use a loop or some sort to copy the file? That wild card directory is dynamic in nature. @Mark

Comment: A wildcard for a directory (if it existed) says to copy the file to multiple directories. So you SHOULD edit your question as to your intent. `For /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /ad "c:\windows\web\*.*" ^| Findstr /c:"<DIR>" ^| Findstr /v /c:"."') do @echo %A`

Comment: @Mark Can you please explain what the command is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would offer this method.

```cmd
For /D %G In ("C:\MyCave\iso\SDG\cmpdir\copy test\ab\cd\*") Do @For %H In ("%G\gh") Do @If "%~aH" GEq "d" Copy /Y "*.zip" "%~H" 1>NUL
```

To begin to understand what the command does, please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, and read the information presented. *You should do the same using `If /?` and `Copy /?` too*.

The first part, `For /D %G In ("FilePath\*")` will return as `%G` directories located in `FilePath`. *(Each of those will be your dynamic/unknown directory names)*.

The next part uses another loop to test each of those unknown directories, with your known directory names appended to it. The results from that loop, *returned as `%H`*, are then checked for the `d`irectory attribute, and if true, the copy command is performed using it.

*Please note, that if there are more than one dynamic directory names containing a subdirectory named `gh`, your `.zip` files will be copied to each of them.*

Comment: Though the command didn't return any error, but it didn't copy anything

Comment: @KrisT, what was your current directory at the time you ran it? _(with an unmodified `Prompt` string, it should be the part at the beginning of the line, before the `>` character)_. `Copy "*.zip"` will copy every `.zip` file in the current directory, if there's none there, they will not be copied! If you want assistance, provide an update in your question, showing the real file/directory names, a directory structure, and acknowledgement of the current directory in your [tag:cmd] window when you run the command. Please also note, in a [tag:batch-file] you'd need to double those  `%` characters.

Comment: *Also @KrisT, if you want to see better what's going on, you can remove the two `@` characters, and the `1>NUL`.*

Comment: I ran the command from the directory where zip file is present. This is the exact directory structure in my workstation. Can I directly this command in cmd terminal or should I run it via a bat file?

Comment: I provided an answer according to your used tags @KrisT, if you do not provide debugging information, I cannot assist you further.

Comment: Hi...I am not before my workstation for the past few hours (due to power failure). I will provide you the debugging output and cmd terminal screenshot tomorrow morning (my time zone) :-)

Comment: Hi @Compo...It has worked after removing @ and 1>NUL portions. Thank you for the effort :)

Comment: No @KrisT, the `@` and `1>NUL` do not affect the running of the command, they simply prevent the printing of unnecessary things to the output location. They absolutely do not suddenly fix anything, you must have made some other mistake.